# UISearchDisplayController with UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableViewController`, in which I added a UISearchBar as the `tableHeaderView` using Interface Builder. Then I added a `UISearchDisplayController` in the nib, and set up all the connections (`delegate`, `searchResultsDelegate`, `searchContentsController`, `searchResultsDataSource`, all connected to the `UITableViewController`). 
I then implemented all the delegate and data source methods in my code.

It works like a charm, except for a weird bug: sometimes the search results table view won't scroll, and I can see the flash indicator of the main table view behind it. I NSLog'd the `searchResultsTableView` and apparently it's a subview of the main tableview, and I guess that's the reason behind the touch problems I described earlier.

What's my mistake? Is it possible to use a `UITableViewController` with `UISearchDisplayController` at all? If so, how do I set up it in such a way that the results table view doesn't get added as a subview of my main table view?

**Update**: I found [this sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) which uses `UISearchDisplayController` with `UITableViewController` and apparently the search table view gets added to the main table view in there as well. So now I don't think that's my problem.

The thing is that I can't find any substantial difference between what I'm doing and what that sample is doing. I'm just adding an `UISearchBar` as a `UITableView` header in a `UITableViewController` and adding a `UISearchDisplayController` to it... It's like iOS is confused between the main table and the search table when I try to scroll. Do you have any ideas?

**Update**: Added a 200 rep bounty. ***Please answer only if you know what you're talking about.***

Comment: Seems like you have a bug in the search functionality and it loops.

Comment: @user792677 Sorry, I don't understand your comment, can you explain?

Comment: Did you add the search bar and the `UISearchDisplayController` separately or dragging the `UISearchDisplayController` directly to the table header view which create all the required connections by itself. I don't know if it makes any difference but we never know.

Comment: And an other tip I can give you is to try to change the background color of the main table view and see if it overlaps the search results table view (and prevents it from scrolling). You said you can see the flash indicator of the main table view which is weird because when I tried the sample, the search results table view completely overlaps the main table view.

Comment: I don't think anyone could answer this question without further info.  Could you reproduce this problem in example code and post a link to it so that people can get a better understanding of your code?

Comment: I didn't think that I will find someone with the same problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was an extra `self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES` which was called as soon as the search data request was finished. Hope it helps anyone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: To the downvoter: please explain? This is nonsense. Someone is having fun downvoting all the answers here.

Comment: Screw the downvoters... You took the initiative and found the solution!  Too many people just give up without putting in the work.

Comment: There are no irregular votes, nor spam flags on this answer. Folks, there is nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: After spending 3 days on this bug we have found (not without the help of your answer) that there is a `tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;` in one of the table view delegate methods. As I understand, once the search results table is opened it is added as a subview to the main table view while the `scrollEnabled` property of the main table view is set to `NO` (all by the search display controller). In my case the `scrollEnabled` property was overridden after that to YES. This caused 2 scrollable table views to be located one inside another and sometimes the OS would pass the scroll to the bottom one

Answer (score 3):

A search display controller manages display of a search bar and a table view that displays the results of a search of data managed by another view controller.

Here the searchDisplaycontroller combines the searchbar and tabelview which showing the result data in the tableview so it won't required separate tableview.

While when you using UISerarchBar then it need to have atleast one UITableView, which can show results in the view. And here you can see the result without even adding the SearchDisplayController to view.

Comment: OK I will edit my answer now as It can be done. I was misunderstood that point. So, What exactly you want to know here?

Comment: Hello, I have read you question and downloaded the code you have linked there. Working on your solutions only. Please wait till I give you the perfect answer.

Comment: A search display controller manages display of a search bar and a table view that displays the results of a search of data managed by another view controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to try adding a UISearchDisplayController IBOutlet to your class and connect that to your SearchdDisplayController in the nib file. I am amusing that that searchdisplay controller in your nib automatically connected it self to the default serachdisaplaycontreoller outlet in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The search bar controller uses its own table view that is added on top of your own. If you set the delegate and dataSource of the UISearchDisplayController to your UITableViewController, then the table view controller has to make a distinction between the two table views in its delegate methods. If you don't do that properly, this may be causing your bug.

In other words:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        return number of rows in data model;
    } else {
        perform the search query;
        return number of rows in search query;
    }
}
```

You do something similar for all of the delegate and dataSource methods.

I'm not 100% sure that this is what's causing your problem, but without seeing more source it's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks but this is not my problem. I'm already doing that distinction, but it's unrelated. The problem is that when I try to scroll the search results table, sometimes it doesn't scroll and I can see the main table's flash indicators (which means the main table view received the touches instead of search table). Additionally, earlier I also saw a new glitch: I have a view in the main table's header, and sometimes when I scroll the search table, this header view in the main table magically appears and overlaps the search table. Weird.

Comment: The usual way to go about fixing such bugs is to build a minimal app and to see if it reproduces this behavior. That will either result in a bug report that you can send Apple, or (more likely) insight into what is going wrong.