# Search view shown always top on tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I took a UITableViewController and trying to add UISearchDisplayController in it. I read many code form the internet but don't know what is wrong with me.

my problem is why UISearchDisplayController not to stick always on top of UITableView.

Here is my Code

```
SearchView_controller.h

@interface SearchView_controller : UITableViewController<UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate>
@end


SearchView_controller.m

@interface SearchView_controller ()
{
    UISearchDisplayController *searchController;
}
@end

@implementation SearchView_controller

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title=@"Test";

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    [searchBar setDelegate:self];

    searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                                                                contentsController:self];
    [searchController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
    [searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
    [searchController setDelegate:self];

    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchController.searchBar];

}

-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UISearchBar *searchBar = searchController.searchBar;
    CGRect rect = searchBar.frame;
    rect.origin.y = MAX(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
    searchBar.frame = rect;
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"searchview_customecell";
    searchview_customecell *cell = (searchview_customecell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.lbl_name.text=@"test";
    return cell;
}

searchview_customecell.h


@interface searchview_customecell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_name;
@end

searchview_customecell.m

@implementation searchview_customecell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Try to do with UIViewController instead of UITableviewController check also this example : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/09/06/search-bar-table-view-storyboard.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to deal with `UIViewController` rather than `UITableviewController` for handling such stuff.

As in case of `UITableViewController` , view is `tableView` so whenever `searchBar` is added it is added on `tableView`.

**There are two possible solutions to this problem:**

1. Either replace Tableviewcontroller with UIViewController and place the Searchbar at the beginning of view (dont add it in tableview header) followed by tableview.
2. Follow this link: [UISearchDisplayController with UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635680/uisearchdisplaycontroller-with-uitableviewcontroller)